# Иномаркам в России покажут красный свет. Можно ли употребить сс «красный свет»?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

С 2017 года иномаркам в России покажут красный свет. 
Т.е. их ввоз будет ограничен. И в кавычках нужно?

Answer (score 2):

**С 2017 года иномаркам в России зажгут "красный свет".**

**Зеленая улица и красный цвет** – фразеологизмы с противоположным значением: предоставить свободный путь без препятствий и задержек или запретить какую-либо деятельность, поставив преграду. В то же время   "зеленая улица" занесена во фразеологические  словари, в отличие от "красного цвета".

Оборот открывать/дать зелёную улицу **может писаться без кавычек**, так как он распространяет исходный фразеологизм (хотя иногда встречается написание в кавычках): Молодым ученым **открыли зеленую улицу** в разработке нового проекта. Произведению дали «зелёную улицу» на страницы журнала.

Оборот зажечь "красный цвет" **обычно заключается в кавычки**, так как  условность выражения не так очевидна, как для "зеленой улицы".

Comment: Учитывая  ответ @Alex_ander  , не хотели бы Вы изменить "с 2017 года" на "в 2017 году"? В самом деле,  "с такого-то года" требует продолжительного действия. И еще. Не следует ли все три слова заключить в кавычки: "зажгут красный свет"?

Comment: Возможно,  действительно, надо заключить три слова в кавычки или не заключать вовсе. С другой стороны,  вот пример: мультипликаторам откроют «зелёную улицу».  Здесь в кавычках только сам фразеологизм. С 2017 года - это с начала  года,  а в 2017 году - неизвестно, когда именно (разный смысл).

Answer (score 0):

Да, кавычки нужны, так как слова употребляются не в своем обычном значении, а фразеологизм "показать красный свет" еще не устоялся.

UPD: Согласен с behemothus, что "*показать* красный свет" звучит не очень.

Comment: Да тут не кавычки нужны... "зажгут красный светя" - я бы еще согласился. И без кавычек. А "показать красный свет"... Ну разве в обезьяньем питомнике. Повернуться задом, задрать хвост и показать...

Answer (score 0):

Это неверно как грамматически, так и стилистически.

1. Обозначению времени "с такого-то года" соответствует продолжительное действие (напр. "будут что-то показывать"), а не однократное ("покажут" - не будут же в руке держать годами!).
2. Глагол "покажут" не сочетается со светофорной метафорой "красный свет": это не "красная карточка", показываемая в играх с мячом. Свет "включают" или "зажигают". Перестановка же глаголов между устойчивыми сочетаниями иногда приводит к ярким находкам ("собака порылась"), но не в этом случае (звучит почти как "зажгут средний палец").

Поэтому, если нужно выразиться метафорически, лучше предпочесть что-то вроде "будут давать от ворот поворот" (или "дадут" его бесповоротно **в** таком-то году).

Comment: Непонятно чем "дать от ворот поворот" лучше чем "зажечь красный свет". Ведь речь идет об автомобилях. Образ светофора как раз к месту.

Comment: "Зажечь красный свет" тоже можно (один раз и не выключать начиная с того года), но понадобятся кавычки, причём я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что в кавычки нужно и глагол заключить, поскольку в этом контексте нельзя представить себе сочетаемых с ним альтернатив.